# How to read numbers after followed by particular Character of a string using Java Android?

Tags: java, android, string, stringreader

```
String str = "[amt is E234.98.valid 23/12/2013.Sample text]"
```

How to read only the amount value from the above sample string which is near after to the character **"E"**.

Comment: put all the possible input value for variable "str", and conclude to a logic where string can be splitted. Other than I doubt whether there is any api present.

Comment: If the text after the value are always 'valid' then the answer is correct, if not, you are going to edit you question to be more specific about the possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regexp and matching groups to extract what you need.

CODE update:

Use by calling `ParseWithRegexp.testIt()`

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ParseWithRegexp {
    static String str = "[amt is E234.98.valid 23/12/2013.Sample text  E134.95.valid 23/12/2015]";
    public static void testIt() {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("E([0-9.]+)\\.valid");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("found: "+m.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Upadte:
You can be more strict with the regexp, for example:
`"E([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)"`

Comment: I cant able to compile your above code...
Im trying to run this code using Android Studio, which is asking me to import these library on build,gradle file

compile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'
compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'

after including of these two libs i've imported these two things from the below packages 
import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
import org.intellij.lang.annotations.Pattern;
But even though i cant able to compile the source code
Suggestion please

Comment: like you said, Ive imported Pattern from 
import java.util.regex.Pattern; package.

Comment: Can you tell me from which package to import the "Matcher"?

Comment: I am using `java.util.regex` from java rt

Comment: the string "valid" which you've used, may come in sentence or may not come in the sentence, if that be the case how to handle it?\

Comment: You can modify regexp to you needs. I wanted to show that you can match something before and something after. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf()` method from `String`, for example:

If you only want what's in bold, and if you must have a dot in your number:

String str = "[amt is E**234.98**.valid 23/12/2013.Sample text]";

Do this:

```
String str = "whatever E2024.1.E";

///Start from the first character after "E"
int startPos = str.indexOf("E") + 1;

///Start from startPos
int dotPos = str.indexOf(".", startPos);

///Start from the first character after dotPos
int endPos = str.indexOf(".", dotPos + 1);

///return the result
return str.substring(startPos, endPos);
```

Otherwise, if you only want the numbers until the first dot do this:

```
String str = "whatever E2024.1.E";

///Start from the first character after "E"
int startPos = str.indexOf("E") + 1;

///Start from the first character after startPos
int endPos = str.indexOf(".", startPos+ 1);

///return the result
return str.substring(startPos, endPos);
```

The only difference is that if you must have a dot present, then you have to check its position and start from it.